# Using object attribute as image source

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass the video object's image attribute as the source so I can display the image on the screen when the program runs. For obvious reasons, it can't find the source, because no file has the name 'videoObj1.image'. I was wondering if there is a workaround, maybe to take the text of the attribute and pass that as a source? Or even a way to directly use videoObj1.image. Thanks in advance.

Part of Question2.html where I try to use the image attribute as the source:

```
function displayVideo(videoObj){

            var html = "<h1>Search Result " + "</h1>" + "<b>";
            html += "Search keyword: " + videoObj.result.searchKeyword;
            html += "<table>";
            for(var i=0; i < videoObj.result.video.length; i++){
            var videoObj1 = videoObj.result.video[i];
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + "<img src=videoObj1.image>" + "</td>";
            html += "<td align='right'>" + videoObj1.channel + "</td>";
            html += "<td style='color:green' align='right'>";
            html += videoObj1.view;
            html += "<img src='stockUp.png' />";
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td align='right'>" + videoObj1.link + "%</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";

            var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
            displayDiv.innerHTML = html;
        }
```

Question2.json:

```
{
"result": {
"searchKeyword": "Mathematics",
"video": [
  {
    "title": "Chaos Game",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "428K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/kbKtFN71Lfs/0.jpg",
    "length": "8:38"
  },
  {
    "title": "Australian Story: Meet Eddie Woo, the maths teacher you wish you'd 
had in high school",
    "channel": "ABC News (Australia)",
    "view": "223K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjIHB8WzJek",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/SjIHB8WzJek/0.jpg",
    "length": "28:08"
  },
  {
    "title": "Ham Sandwich Problem",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "557K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCXmUi56rao",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCXmUi56rao/0.jpg",
    "length": "5:53"
  },
  {
    "title": "Magic Square Party Trick",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "312K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aQxCnmhqZko/0.jpg",
    "length": "3:57"
  },
  {
    "title": "The 8 Queen Problem",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "909K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPcBU0Z2Hj8",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jPcBU0Z2Hj8/0.jpg",
    "length": "7:03"
  }
  ]
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing the string `"videoObj1.image"` to the img src attribute, which obviously is not going to work.

Rather you should pass the variable either by using classic string concatenation approach like this:

```
   "<td><img src=" + videoObj1.image + "></td>";
```

OR

Using the recommended and modern [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) approach like this:

```
   `<td><img src=${videoObj1.image}></td>`;
```